# Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixComponentGroup:MyWebWebComponents' in section 'Product:*'.

Tags: wix

I'm trying to fix a WiX installer for one of our products, but when I rebuild the WiX-project I get an error saying:

```
Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixComponentGroup:MyWebWebComponents' in section 'Product:*'.
```

It is referencing to this part in the `Product.wxs` file:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SociopackWebApiSetup" Level="1">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyWebWebComponents" />
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="SociopackWebserviceIssConfiguration" />
</Feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by running `msbuild /t:Harvest;WIX;DeleteTmpFiles setup.build` in the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015